# For as long as dark corners still "lurk" in our heart?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I found this sentence in a translation:

> For as long as dark corners still ***lurk*** in our heart, we cannot claim to direct others to the light.

Now can "lurk" be applied to a non-animate subject? My instinct says no, but as I am not a native speaker, I cannot trust myself 100%. If "lurk" does not apply, which word would be appropriate?

**Edit:** After all the enlightening comments I received I decided to add this. It dawned on me that I always associated ***lurk*** with *movement* and if you look at its synonyms [here](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/lurk.html#C0-1) you will see why. Corners do not move and cannot *find a place to hide* or *loiter*. In a literature context you can certainly make anything move, and probably in metaphors you can do that also, but still..,

Comment: If something such as a danger, doubt, or fear lurks somewhere, it exists but is not obvious or easily recognized.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lurk

Comment: @user121863: I am tempted to see a personification of danger here. So you think it is ok to personify _dark corners_, too?

Comment: What does  _dark corners lurk in our heart_ mean? It is a weird kind of metaphor, if it's one. You might try _reside_ or _harbour_ instead, but the meaning would not remain same.

Comment: In the original Greek text, the author states (word by word) that _if dark corners still **exist** in our heart_ and the rest. I do not dislike _lurk_ at all, I was simply not sure if it was appropriate. By the way, can _harbour_ be used intransitively?

Comment: It's a little strange, but probably the best fit for the translation.  "Poetic", so absolutely "logical" semantics is not required.

Comment: I see. Sure it can be. Please check M-W :)

Comment: Usually, things lurk in dark corners.  The corners themselves don’t lurk.  But “As long as darkness lurks in our heart...” seems to retain the meaning.

Comment: Yes, I must say that this was my thought too... I now understand from LPH's answer that inanimate things can lurk, but "corners", although they are abstract in my example, still refer to something concrete which _does not lurk_ because it can't move... But maybe I am splitting the hairs too much?

Comment: It may have been a literal translation. Perhaps closer would have been "*... darkness still lurks within the corners of our heart ...*". But I would contend, a *dark corner* may *lurk* in the sense that you may not know that it is there until pointed out to you.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few constatations, which, if convincing, could add to your information.

This verb can be used with abstract subjects since it is used widely with the word "danger" and other words representing abstract concepts : "[danger lurking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=danger+lurking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdanger%20lurking%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdanger%20lurking%3B%2Cc0), [the danger that lurks](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+danger+that+lurks&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20danger%20that%20lurks%3B%2Cc0)".

[ref. 1, 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ESZDqNQmb5gC&pg=PT300&dq=%22danger+lurking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKv4zMwcPtAhXNxIUKHQMxBKUQ6AEwB3oECCcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22danger%20lurking%22&f=false) Yet when one asks women about danger, their fears translate into concerns about the danger lurking in the physical environment: car parks, public stairwells and public transport, for instance, are typically named by women as dangerous

[ref. 2, 1975](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EZdLAAAAYAAJ&q=%22lurks%22&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7qdSvw8PtAhWGGBQKHYamC-AQ6AEwDHoECDYQAg) Who Knows what Lurks in the Mind of a Child?

[ref. 3, 2007](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kJ1CAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7qdSvw8PtAhWGGBQKHYamC-AQ6AEwKHoECEMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22lurks%22&f=false) That is, there is to be no information that lurks inaccessible within the system. Pieces of information not to be displayed for security reasons (such as passwords, hashed data, or data encrypted using a key unknown to the user) or for other valid

As "dark corner" in this context can't be anything else than an abstract concept, it should be justified to use the verb "to lurk", although I must admit, the analogical connection that is made with the concrete concept of a dark corner in a building  can make the combination appear strange; nevertheless, all that can be retained is the abstract concept, which,  as a metaphorical rendering, is something spiritual removed from the common run of the spiritual activity a human being is subject to, as in a house a dark corner that, in order to be a dark corner, can't be where the life of the house is concentrated.

It is true that inanimates are not often used as subjects. Here is an instance though where the inanimate, if "a world" can be so called, is used as subject.

[ref. 4, 2001](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_49YTKJ16l4C&pg=PA6&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7qdSvw8PtAhWGGBQKHYamC-AQ6AEwQXoECBIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22lurks%22&f=false) Beneath the glossy surface of official design lurks a dark and strange world driven by real human needs.

Here below is another one, more convincing, since the degree to which  light can be endowed with "life" is not as great as for a world.

[ref. 5, 2015](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N5HmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLrpCJycPtAhUgA2MBHedQDMM4ZBDoATADegQIBhAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurks%22&f=false) Girl in the Dark - Page 137

[image]

The use of the word "lurk" must however be taken as metaphorical.

In this next reference can be found used as subject of "lurk" the ultimate inanimate in a gradation from the animate to the inanimate.

[ref. 6, 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ob-aAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLrpCJycPtAhUgA2MBHedQDMM4ZBDoATAnegQIXBAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurks%22&f=false) Younger Next Week: Your Ultimate Rx to Reverse the Clock, ...

[image]

Below can be found a confirmation of your understanding that "lurk" is  hardly used with inanimates; this characteristic is so essential that it confers to the word the property of giving life to the inanimate.

[ref. 7, 2000](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HtVJVdWY2toC&pg=PA225&dq=%22lurks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLrpCJycPtAhUgA2MBHedQDMM4ZBDoATA5egQIRBAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurks%22&f=false) Consider these two sentences:
The table is stationary.
The table lurks stationary.
Notice how "lurks" as a metaphor doesn't just animate the table, it animates the writer.

Follows now a figurative use of the verb where the subject is perfect inanimates.

[ref. 8, 2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=r0S11DeegFkC&pg=PA143&dq=%22lurk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-f7r8cPtAhVk7eAKHYYkCKo4ZBDoATBHegQIExAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurk%22&f=false) With oil and gas reserves thought to lurk beneath those waters, the stakes will rise as China's economy grows ever more thirsty for growth-sustaining energy sources.

[ref. 9, 2011](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RnzIAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22lurk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-f7r8cPtAhVk7eAKHYYkCKo4ZBDoATBIegQIEhAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurk%22&f=false) The objective of this paper is to warn and alert social networking users of the dangers that lurk on popular sites such

[ref. 10, 2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=tNLugjHej0MC&pg=PA139&dq=%22lurk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-f7r8cPtAhVk7eAKHYYkCKo4ZBDoATBWegQILhAC#v=onepage&q=%22lurk%22&f=false) Demons and other adversaries lurk at every turn in the road, ready to ambush.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extensive answer! Have you noticed that in ALL your examples _the thing_ that lurks is in the singular? This is another aspect that put me off from "lurk".

Comment: @fev *ALL your examples the thing that lurks is in the singular* This is irrelevant. You can pluralise all the pronouns and  non-count nouns and the sentences will remain valid.

Comment: @Greybeard: You are perfectly right. I am just trying to eliminate all my doubts by asking LPH if the fact that my context is in the plural makes any difference.

Comment: @fev This is understandable as I based my research on the word "lurks" only. I will add some examples.

Comment: @LPH: And _**lurk**_ it shall be then! I wonder if what enables those "corners" to lurk is the fact that they are dark...

Comment: @fev Yes, lurking rhymes with the backwaters, dimmed lights, somber moods…

Comment: The key is perhaps your observation that a corners is especially "non-animate". To lurk, we need to be able to imagine it moving around. I can imagine a streetlamp sliding along the block, but a corner dragging its geometry along with it?

Comment: @OwenReynolds "To lurk, we need to be able to imagine it moving around."  I wholly disagree.  When I imagine something lurking, it's not moving at all -- at least, not when I'm looking right at it.  To lurk is to "be or remain hidden so as to wait in ambush for someone or something." (oxford)  It's much more difficult to remain hidden when moving around.  I have been ambushed by inanimate objects many times. For other examples, have a look at some videos of cats vs. cucumbers.

Comment: In the specific case of dark corners, I believe they generally lurk transitively via the imaginary horrors they contain, constructed by the subject's mind.

Comment: @OwenReynolds  Taking "corner" literally, yes, it is non-animate  (there must be delimiting material elements if we want to say something is a corner),  but taking it metaphorically, no, "corner" becomes something **abstract**, not non-animate (personally, I think that what is abstract is neither animate nor non-animate, those two categories being always concrete (rather concrete is the animate)). I see that you have the idea of a perfect analogy; this is a misconception: analogies are rough comparisons, very rough at times, and here, (1/3)

Comment: @OwenReynolds  your  idea of a moving metaphorical abstract corner, as great a marvel of perfection as it might be deemed to be by literary people, goes much too far. It is so for countless other analogies. Again, in your apprehension of the metaphor about the street light that we have in the examples, you shouldn't go so far; there is no way you can. The metaphorical lurking of the street light is of a slightly different kind; there is now a new element in the abstraction: poetry is added to the metaphor: we do find prose sometimes that has the stamp of poetry. (2/3)

Comment: @OwenReynolds The narrator expresses the displeasure that light occasions while he is seeking the darkness in the outdoors and that can tell us that  this light, however so feeble, oppresses him, nags him, makes him feel insecure, as might do the real lurking of a wolf perhaps; so he doesn't indulge in circling the lawn all night. There is no notion of sliding light. (3/3)

Comment: @Timbo Exactly "*at least, not when I'm looking right at it*". Lurking is going there then choosing not to move. Even if we accuse a cucumber of lurking, we're suggesting it purposely rolled to that spot. As for corners implying their contents, ugg. "Wayward thoughts lurking in dark corners" is smoother than a lurking corner.